# How to extract text from specific div class using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically I want to extract the text inside

```
<div class = "examplediv">
example text
</div>
```

I used

```
url='https://sample.com'
headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"class":"examplediv"})
clean_data = data.text
print(clean_data)
```

but it never fails to return with "None" in the terminal.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

try `find_all` instead of `find` in case if the same class name is repeated so you might just getting the first item. `find_all` should return a list of items for you. otherwise you might be dealing with `class` under `event` which is loaded via `JavaScript` which will not be rendered via `requests` module. you will need to use `selenium` in that case, or share the `url` so we can manually check other methods.